# Hibernate Criteria with multiple level join

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 3 linked classes with @OneToMany relation

Luce.class

```
public class Luce implements java.io.Serializable{

    private Client client;
}
```

Client.class

```
public class Client implements java.io.Serializable{

        private Server server;
    }
```

Server.class

```
public class Server implements java.io.Serializable{

        private Piano Piano;
    }
```

I need to get the List of Luce from a specified Piano.
So, in the implementation of my DAO interface i was trying to do the following:

```
Criteria criteria = createEntityCriteria();
        criteria.createAlias("client", "c");
        criteria.createAlias("server", "s");
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("c.s.piano", piano);
```

but i get the exception

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: server of: it.besmart.models.Luce
```

Comment: please provide mapping of classes

Comment: Try with `criteria.createAlias("c.server", "s")` instead of `criteria.createAlias("server", "s")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to create an alias of the property server on Luce so it won't work.

```
Criteria criteria = createEntityCriteria();
    criteria.createAlias("client", "c");
    criteria.createAlias("c.server", "s");
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("s.piano", piano);
```